# Low exponent attack against RSA

Tags: rsa

According to this:
http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/rsa.pdf

One can calculate the message m, if there was no padding scheme involved.

My question: is it possible to find m if the $n_a n_b n_c$ moduli are unknown?

Also: if one can see the encrypted version of a known plaintext, can one find the modulus?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on secret RSA moduli: [Hans-Joachim Knobloch - Breaking Public Keys - How to Determine an Unknown RSA Public Modulus](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/588).

Comment: Many thanks! Although, I only know the three same plaintext, and their respective remainders, modulo three randomly generated 1024 bit keys.